# Bash script can't recognize variable as part of path

Tags: shell-script, sudo, environment-variables

This if statement:

```
if [ -n ${OSSIEHOME} ] && [ -d ${OSSIEHOME}/share/aclocal/ossie ]; then
    OSSIE_AC_INCLUDE=${OSSIEHOME}/share/aclocal/ossie
else
    echo "Error: Cannot find the OSSIE aclocal files. This is not expected!"
```

Constantly defaults to the error message. I know that `OSSIEHOME` has a value because if I do `echo $OSSIEHOME` from the command line I get

```
/usr/local/redhawk/core
```

And if I then hard code that path into my script it works fine. Problem is, I have a few other, much larger scripts where going through and hard coding the correct path isn't an option. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
`od -c <<<"$OSSIEHOME"` gives me this:

```
0000000 / u s r / l o c a l / r e d h a
0000020 w k / c o r e \n
0000030
```

`ls -l /usr/local/redhawk/core/share/aclocal/` gives me this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 19 10:02 ossie
```

Running the script with `bash -x` gives:

```
+ rm -f config.cache
+ '[' -e /usr/local/share/aclocal/libtool.m4 ']'
+ '[' -e /usr/share/aclocal/libtool.m4 ']'
+ /bin/cp /usr/share/aclocal/libtool.m4 acinclude.m4
+ libtoolize --force --automake
+ '[' -n ']'
+ '[' -d /share/aclocal/ossie ']'
+ echo 'Error: Cannot find the OSSIE aclocal files. This is not expected!'
Error: Cannot find the OSSIE aclocal files. This is not expected!
+ '[' -n ']'
+ aclocal -I
aclocal: error: option '-I' requires an argument
aclocal: Try '/bin/aclocal --help' for more information.
+ autoconf
+ automake --foreign --add-missing
```

I tried to export `OSSIEHOME` to make it global (just in case) but that didn't work. I then tried to run the script at `. script.sh` and `source script.sh` problem is I need to run the script with sudo or it won't have the necessary permissions to work. if I do though I get the error

```
sudo: source: command not found
```

Comment: I wonder if there are "invisible" characters in there. What does `od -c <<<"$OSSIEHOME"` show you?

Comment: Are you running `echo $OSSIEHOME` in the same environment as the terminal in which you are running the script?

Comment: `od -c <<<"$OSSIEHOME"` gives me this:

   

 `0000000   /   u   s   r   /   l   o   c   a   l   /   r   e   d   h   a
    0000020   w   k   /   c   o   r   e  \n
    0000030`

Comment: @user4556274 yes I am running both the script and the echo command in the same environment

Comment: And the output of `ls -l /usr/local/redhawk/core/share/aclocal/` ?  (When responding to comments, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/385258/edit) your question with the additional information, rather than with another comment.)

Comment: And if you change your test to `if [[ -d ${OSSIEHOME?}/share/aclocal/ossie ]]`?

Comment: `[ -n ${OSSIEHOME} ]` would return true if $OSSIEHOME was empty as you forgot to quote the variable. You forgot to quote all variables actually.

Comment: Try running your script with `bash -x` to see what happens.

Comment: As @StéphaneChazelas and I suspected, your variable is not initialized.

Comment: Why would the variable not be initialized if I can see its value from the command line?

Comment: Your script does not inherit all variables that have been set in your current shell.

Comment: Ok I tried a couple of things. First I tried to `export OSSIEHOME` to make it global (just in case) but that didn't work. I then tried to run the script at `. script.sh` and `source script.sh` problem is I need to run the script with sudo or it won't have the necessary permissions to work. if I do though I get the error `sudo: source: command not found`

Comment: `sudo` is important information not stated in your question (contrary to your earlier comment, you were _not_ running the script in the same environment as the `echo` command... unless you were running `sudo echo`).  Try running as `sudo -E`  (preserve environment of the original user).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been diagnosed in comments in the question. In my answer I'll explain what's going on and how to fix it.

The code

> ```
> if [ -n ${OSSIEHOME} ] && [ -d ${OSSIEHOME}/share/aclocal/ossie ]; then
> ```

is dangerous because you're using unquoted variable expansions. `"${OSSIEHOME}"` or just `"$OSSIEHOME"` expands to the value of the variable but `${OSSIEHOME}` outside quotes is split into words. In particular, if the variable is empty or unset then the command to the left of the `&&` operator expands to `[` `-n` `]` which is true. You can see in the trace produced by `bash -x` that `[` `-n` `]` is executed. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for more details. From now on, remember to always put double quotes around variable and command substitutions¹.

```
if [ -n "${OSSIEHOME}" ] && [ -d "${OSSIEHOME}/share/aclocal/ossie" ]; then
  …
```

This will fix the broken error reporting. But you still need to ensure that the variable is set when the script runs. It isn't enough to check that `echo $OSSIEHOME` prints something in your current shell. You need to ensure that the variable is in the environment. If you only do run `OSSIEHOME=/usr/local/redhawk/core`, that sets a shell variable only. To set an environment variable, you need to run `export OSSIEHOME=/usr/local/redhawk/core` (or `OSSIEHOME=/usr/local/redhawk/core` and then `export OSSIEHOME`).

You add that you're invoking the script through `sudo`. In typical configurations, sudo removes most variables from the environment. (This is vital for security when users are only allowed to run specific commands, but it's an annoyance without any strong security benefit if you're allowed to run arbitrary commands with sudo.) So you need to explicitly tell sudo to set this variable when you run the script.

```
sudo OSSIEHOME=/usr/local/redhawk/core /path/to/your/script
```

If the variable is already set in the shell's environment and you don't want to repeat the value, you can use

```
sudo OSSIEHOME="$OSSIEHOME" /path/to/your/script
```

Alternatively, you may or may not be allowed to run `sudo -E /path/to/your/script`. The `-E` option tells sudo to preserve most environment variables.

Running `source` or `.` with sudo doesn't work because these are shell builtins, not executable commands. They are shell builtins because of what they do: run a script in *the same shell that's already running*, i.e. it's an instruction in the shell to go and read commands from a file, not an instruction to execute a separate program. This cannot make any sense with sudo: if the script was running in the same shell process, it would be running with the same privileges.

¹  <sub>For advanced users, add “unless you know why you need to omit them”.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. And to clarify I didn't run the script originally with sudo just when I tried to run `source` or `.` I'll keep this in mind when editing other scripts